# Bitcoincharts API get mtgox bid value

Tags: bitcoind

How do i get the mtgox bid , current_volume or other things using Bitcoincharts API?

for example:`http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/trades.csv?symbol=mtgoxUSD`

gives you the latest trades...but what if i want only the bid value how would i do it using the url above?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think bitcoin charts is exactly what you're after. If you MUST use it then you'll find the information you're looking for at http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json however this includes all markets and not just mtgoxUSD ([API overview is here](http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/)).

I would suggest using the mtGox API directly, information can be found at the [bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP/v1) and this explains exactly how you could go about getting current volume etc.

To get the volume you would need to either look at the JSON displayed on this page http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker or parse it into whatever language you're processing this data with.